# Python : subprocess.check_output() doesn't return

Tags: python, subprocess

Im using python's `subprocess.check_output()` to run `main.py` from `wrapper.py` (*Windows*)

After running in debug mode and analyzing with logger, I came to know that `check_output` is not returning back to `wrapper.py;` and at wrapper, it keeps waiting for subprocess to finish.

Previously it was working fine, after running many times I'm seeing this problem.
Didn't do any changes in the code.

Comment: How do you know with certainty that your main.py python process has finished?   What have you used as evidence of that?

Comment: previously it was taking around 2 mins.. now even if I wait for half an hour its still waiting! and after that I used to force stop. I did force stop many times by now...